# Universal phonegap video player?

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am building a phonegap application targeted at different devices(mainly Android and IOS). I wanted to play a local mp4 video. I tried using [this plugin](https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer) and others but they are built for android as I understand. Is there a universal solution to this problem i.e Is there any way I Can build without worrying which device I am targeting? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try the video tag

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```